# AVX2 SIMD XOR not yielding performance improvements in .NET

Tags: c#, .net-core, simd, intrinsics, .net-core-3.0

I'm playing around with .NET Core 3.0's new support for hardware intrinsics, in the System.Runtime.Intrinsics namespace.

I have some code where I perform 4 XOR operations in a loop - below is a simplified example (I didn't write this in an IDE, so please ignore any syntax mistakes:

```cs
private static unsafe ulong WyHashCore(byte[] array)
{
    fixed (byte* pData = array)
    {
        byte* ptr = pData;

        // Consume 32-byte chunks
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i += 32)
        {
            ulong a = Read64(ptr, i);
            ulong b = Read64(ptr, i + 8);
            ulong c = Read64(ptr, i + 16);
            ulong d = Read64(ptr, i + 24);

            // XOR them with some constants
            ulong xor1 = a ^ SOME_CONSTANT1;
            ulong xor2 = b ^ SOME_CONSTANT2;
            ulong xor3 = c ^ SOME_CONSTANT3;
            ulong xor4 = d ^ SOME_CONSTANT4;

            // Use the resulting values
        }
    }
}
```

The `Read64` method looks like:

```cs
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
internal static unsafe ulong Read64(byte* ptr, int start)
    => *(ulong*)(ptr + start);
```

I tried replacing the 4 XOR lines with:

```cs
byte[] array; // An array from elsewhere

private static unsafe ulong WyHashCore(byte[] array)
{
    var bVector = Vector256.Create(SOME_CONSTANT1, SOME_CONSTANT2, SOME_CONSTANT3, SOME_CONSTANT4);

    fixed (byte* pData = array)
    {
        byte* ptr = pData;

        // Consume 32-byte chunks
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i += 32)
        {
            ulong a = Read64(ptr, i);
            ulong b = Read64(ptr, i + 8);
            ulong c = Read64(ptr, i + 16);
            ulong d = Read64(ptr, i + 24);

            // Create a 256-bit vector from the 4 64-bit integers
            var aVector = Vector256.Create(a, b, c, d);

            // XOR the 2 vectors
            var res = Avx2.Xor(aVector, bVector);

            // Get the resulting values out of the result vector
            ulong xor1 = res.GetElement(0);
            ulong xor2 = res.GetElement(1);
            ulong xor3 = res.GetElement(2);
            ulong xor4 = res.GetElement(3);

            // Use the resulting values
        }
    }
}
```

This does give the expected results - but it's 15x *slower* than just multiplying the scalars!

Am I going wrong somewhere, or mis-using SIMD?

** Update **
I've updated the code to use the 'correct' ways of loading and offloading data to/from the vector, and it's now around 3.75x faster than the scalar code!

```cs
byte[] array; // An array from elsewhere
private static readonly Vector256<ulong> PrimeVector = Vector256.Create(SOME_CONSTANT1, SOME_CONSTANT2, SOME_CONSTANT3, SOME_CONSTANT4);

private static unsafe ulong WyHashCore(byte[] array)
{
    // Create space on the stack to hold XOR results
    var xorResult = stackalloc ulong[4];

    fixed (byte* pData = array)
    {
        byte* ptr = pData;

        // Consume 32-byte chunks
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i += 32)
        {
            // Create a 256-bit vector from the 4 64-bit integers
            var vector = Avx.LoadVector256((ulong*)(ptr + i));

            // XOR the 2 vectors
            var res = Avx2.Xor(vector, PrimeVector);

            // Store the resulting vector in memory
            Avx2.Store(xorResult, res);

            // Get the resulting values out of the result vector
            var xor1 = *xorResult;
            var xor2 = *(xorResult + 1);
            var xor3 = *(xorResult + 2);
            var xor4 = *(xorResult + 3);

            // Use the resulting values
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post more complete code. The loop in the 2nd example would be important to see. I think you're supposed to read the bytes directly from memory and not using `Vector256.Create(a, b, c, d)`. Also, must store like that I think. This element wise loading and storing has high overhead.

Comment: @usr my intent here was to keep things readable, to focus on the problem at hand, but I can see how the specifics could be relevant - I've updated the code samples to better match reality

Comment: @usr I just tried loading the vector in the loop with `Avx2.LoadVector256((ulong*)(ptr + p));` - this is indeed much faster than using `Vector256.Create`!

This gets me to roughly performance parity with the scalar version. Surely it can be made faster...

Comment: Please always keep posting the best code you have. Make sure to store the results directly to memory as well. Also, please post a disassembly listing. And surely you are running in Release mode without debugger attached, right?

Comment: @usr Yes, I'm benchmarking using Benchmark.NET, in release mode with no debugger. How do I go about storing the results directly to memory? (I'm new to C#'s `Vector`).

I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/cocowalla/bb7e735b988a8cfec9770f1a0ee6a4a6) showing the C#, IL and ASM generated by the JIT

Comment: I can't tell you the right way to do it because I'm not an expert at this. But surely there exists a store instruction for vectors, right? From what I understand it is best to not even use pointers but to use `ref` and possibly `Unsafe.Add` for pointer arithmetic. That way you are using managed pointers which are easier to use than unmanaged pointers. Maybe they generate better code as well, who knows.

Comment: @usr I did some micro-optimisation benchmarks before, and `Unsafe.Add` is basically the same performance-wise as unsafe pointers. I personally find pointers less verbose and easier to read than using `Unsafe`, but I guess it's a matter of taste. There is an `Avx.Store` method - I'll investigate that!

Comment: Using `Avx.Store` was very successful - the SIMD version is now 3.75x faster than the scalar version! I'll write up an answer with the updated code - thanks for helping out @usr :)

Comment: It seems that the .NET API does not support Avx2.Store. Maybe there's a typo in your code and you have actually used Avx.Store?

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR The AVX2 HW intrinsics are used incorrectly what results in generation of very inefficient SIMD code.**

The error lies in a way the instructions load, operate on and store data in a buffer. The operation should be performed using AVX/AVX2 Avx2.Xor intrinsics with memory what will speedup load time 4x and would return Vector256. This on the other hand would make call to Vector256.Create redundant and would speedup execution further. Finally, the data should be stored in the array by using Avx2.Store() intrinsic. This again would speedup the code roughly 4x.

The last optimization which should be applied is an exploitation of CPU instruction level parallelism. Usually SIMD instructions are executed over predefined number of CPU cycles with latency which maybe larger than 1 CPU cycle. These parameters are CPU specific and can be found in:

- [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm),
- [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#)
- [Agner Fog's
  Instruction tables: Lists of instruction latencies, throughputs and
  micro-operation breakdowns for Intel, AMD and VIA CPUs](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf)

As all optimizations which could be applied are quite complex I will explain them in longer writeup a bit later but in general I would expect up to 4x speedup due to vectorisation in comparison to base case for the problem you are working on.

The code sample you are using is a simple loop modifying data in quad unsigned quadword steps and is a perfect candidate for autovectorization by optimizing compilers. When identical C++ loop is optimized by GCC 9.1 with options *-O3 -march=haswell* the resulting machine code shows all standard optimizations applied to the loop:

```
#include <cstdint>
void hash(uint64_t* buffer, uint64_t length) {

    uint64_t* pBuffer = buffer;
    const uint64_t CONST1 = 0x6753ul;
    const uint64_t CONST2 = 0x7753ul;
    const uint64_t CONST3 = 0x8753ul;
    const uint64_t CONST4 = 0x9753ul;

    for(uint64_t i = 0; i < length; i += 4)
    {
        *pBuffer ^= CONST1;
        *(pBuffer + 1) ^= CONST2;
        *(pBuffer + 2) ^= CONST3;
        *(pBuffer + 3) ^= CONST4;
    }
}
```

[Godbolt Compiler Explorer result GCC 9.1](https://godbolt.org/z/wi5q48)

```
    test    rsi, rsi
    je      .L11
    cmp     rsi, -4
    ja      .L6
    lea     rdx, [rsi-1]
    vmovdqa ymm1, YMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
    xor     eax, eax
    shr     rdx, 2
    inc     rdx
.L5:
    vpxor   ymm0, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rdi]
    inc     rax
    add     rdi, 32
    vmovdqu YMMWORD PTR [rdi-32], ymm0
    cmp     rax, rdx
    jb      .L5
    vzeroupper
.L11:
    ret
.L6:
    vmovdqa ymm1, YMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
    xor     eax, eax
.L3:
    vpxor   ymm0, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rdi]
    add     rax, 4
    add     rdi, 32
    vmovdqu YMMWORD PTR [rdi-32], ymm0
    cmp     rsi, rax
    ja      .L3
    vzeroupper
    jmp     .L11
.LC0:
    .quad   26451
    .quad   30547
    .quad   34643
    .quad   38739
```

[Godbolt Compiler Explorer result Clang 8.0](https://godbolt.org/z/KqdP_l)

```
 .LCPI0_0:
    .quad   26451                   # 0x6753
    .quad   30547                   # 0x7753
    .quad   34643                   # 0x8753
    .quad   38739                   # 0x9753
 hash(unsigned long*, unsigned long):                             # @hash(unsigned long*, unsigned long)
    test    rsi, rsi
    je      .LBB0_3
    xor     eax, eax
    vmovaps ymm0, ymmword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0] # ymm0 = [26451,30547,34643,38739]
 .LBB0_2:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    vxorps  ymm1, ymm0, ymmword ptr [rdi + 8*rax]
    vmovups ymmword ptr [rdi + 8*rax], ymm1
    add     rax, 4
    cmp     rax, rsi
    jb      .LBB0_2
 .LBB0_3:
    vzeroupper
    ret
```

Comment: Unfortunately .NET doesn't do auto-vectorization :(  Very keen to find out what you have in mind with CPU instruction level parallelism!

Comment: @Cocowalla: create ILP for the CPU to exploit by for example summing an array of `float` with 8 `sum0`, `sum1`, `sum2`, ... variables, so there are 8 dependency chains of `sum0 += arr[i]`.  (But instead of scalar variables, use SIMD vectors as accumulators, so your code can have 4 or 8 *vector* additions in-flight at once to hide the latency of FP add).  See [latency vs throughput in intel intrinsics](//stackoverflow.com/a/40879258) and [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables?](//stackoverflow.com/q/45113527)

Comment: Also for an intro to how CPUs exploit ILP, [see this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349972/how-does-a-single-thread-run-on-multiple-cores/350024#350024).  e.g. 4 scalar `xor` operations can run in parallel, so if you do need to do some non-vectorizable stuff with XOR results, you're probably best just writing it scalar.

Comment: @Cocowalla: Extracting from SIMD vectors to integers has similar or more cost to just doing scalar loads and scalar xor.  Although maybe if you do a SIMD load, SIMD XOR, then store the result to a 32-byte array and reload from there you could win on throughput, and only need 1 vector constant instead of 4 scalar constants in integer registers or memory source operands, if they don't fit in 32-bit sign-extended immediates.  Not latency but that's not too important assuming OoO exec can keep multiple iterations of your loop in flight (if it's not too huge).

Comment: @Peter-Cordes the answer you pointed to was really helpful in better understanding why SIMD gains may not be as expected, thanks!